# Generic & Specific Functions in Structures

Tags: rust

I've been struggling with building a class which holds a user inputted function. While I can actually get that to work on its own, the trouble arises when I try to provide a creation method which uses a default function. A toy example illustrating the problem is shown below, and can be found at this [Playground Link](http://is.gd/rOa00B)

```
fn main() {
    let a = Apply::mini(2);
    println!("{}", a.apply());
}`

struct Apply<F, I> {
    f: F,
    i: I,
}

impl<F, I> Apply<F, I> {
    fn new(f: F, i: I) -> Apply<F, I> {
        Apply{ f: f, i: i }
    }
}

impl<F, I> Apply<F, I> where F: Fn(I) -> i32 {
    fn apply(self) -> i32 {
        (self.f)(self.i)
    }
}

impl Apply<Fn(i32) -> i32, i32> {
    fn mini(i: i32) -> Apply<Fn(i32) -> i32, i32> {
        Apply::new(|x| x + 1, i)
    }
}
```

This implementation rightfully complains that a Fn(i32) -> i32 is unsized. The only way I can think of to circumvent that is to pull it out as a type parameter, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unboxed closures in Rust are implemented as anonymous types implementing certain traits. "Anonymous" means, naturally, that they can't be named - and so it is impossible ([at least now](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/518)) to return unboxed closures by value from functions.

There are two ways for you to solve this particular problem. First, because your closure in `mini()` does not capture anything, you can use regular functions:

```
impl Apply<fn(i32) -> i32, i32> {
    fn mini1(i: i32) -> Apply<fn(i32) -> i32, i32> {
        fn add_one(x: i32) -> i32 { x + 1 }
        Apply::new(add_one, i)
    }
}
```

Second, if you do need to use capturing closures, you have to use `Box`:

```
impl Apply<Box<Fn(i32) -> i32>, i32> {
    fn mini2(i: i32) -> Apply<Box<Fn(i32) -> i32>, i32> {
        Apply::new(Box::new(|x| x + 1), i)
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why, but for this to work I had to implement `apply2()` method specifically for boxes (which really looks like a bug to me):

```
impl<I> Apply<Box<Fn(I) -> i32>, I> {
    fn apply2(self) -> i32 {
        (self.f)(self.i)
    }
}
```

(try it all [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f71ed2eb58dd0b658e19&version=stable))

**Update:** [here](http://is.gd/SRDLx7) is a link to code by @ker which doesn't require the second `apply` method. It uses a nice trick with `Deref` to allow `apply()` to be used with boxed trait objects.

Comment: `Box` doesn't implement the `Fn` trait, that might be the reason

Comment: you can fix the `apply` function by requiring `Deref<Fn(I) -> i32>`: http://is.gd/SRDLx7

Comment: @ker, that's strange, aren't trait objects automatically implement the trait they are formed from? I thought that was one of the main reasons for making `Self` unsized by default. The variant with `Deref` is really nice anyway.

Comment: yea I think the only "real" trait objects left in Rust are `&Trait`

Comment: Thanks for the wisdom, guys. The use of Deref is pretty slick, although you still need 2 impl's for apply, right (one with Deref for Boxed closures, one without for normal functions which do not impl Deref)? I say this as just [a Deref impl](http://is.gd/yMEDDp) doesn't seem to work.
Unless I'm thinking about this wrong.

Comment: @AlexOzdemir, hm, indeed, looks like it. This whole thing seems very strange to me anyway, I have expected that your original apply would work for trait objects as well. Maybe it is worth to open a ticket in Rust issue tracker,